# How to convert &[u8] to impl Iterator<Item = u8>?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice

I want to pass `&[u8]` into a function that takes a `u8` iterator:

```rust
fn f(words: &[u8]) {
    g(words.iter())
}

fn g(words: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) {
    //
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59ed85c4b1a0ec9950b87fe5842c3e5b)

The above doesn't work. It errors with:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, u8> as Iterator>::Item == u8`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     g(words.iter())
  |     ^ expected `u8`, found reference
...
6 | fn g(words: impl Iterator<Item = u8>) {
  |                           --------- required by this bound in `g`
  |
  = note:   expected type `u8`
          found reference `&u8`
```

This is because the iterator is implemented as passing a reference, not the value. Is there a way to make this work without changing the signature of `g`?

Answer (score 1):

You need an owned version of the data, `u8` instead of the `&u8` returned by the iterator.

Use [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Cloned.html) on the iterator:

```rust
fn f(words: &[u8]) {
    g(words.iter().cloned())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=870eded7ab67d4577dec0dec4c4e7ea9)

Comment: Please search for duplicate questions before answering. Knowing an answer gives you a unique ability to find the duplicates that the question asker doesn't have.